How can I style XML to render the source in broswers?
I understand this is a niche question. I have need for a client side web app to show the user some XML. The default XML renderer (say as a data:text/xml,… based iframe) in most browsers is perfect for this except they place a message at the top of the document:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

How can I instruct the browser to shoe the document tree but without the missing style information warning?
I've discovered that you can add your own stylesheet to the XML but this will remove the document tree and render it as HTML instead. That makes sense when you want to do that but I'm specifically wanting to show the document tree.
There is this trick using clip-path which works but I'm unsure how cross browser compatible it is (I did this in FireFox).


const doc = document.getElementById('example');
const xml = `<foo type="example"><bar>lorem</bar></foo>`.trim();
doc.src = `data:text/xml,${encodeURIComponent(xml)}`;
iframe {
  clip-path: polygon(0 90px, 100% 90px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin-top: -90px;
}
  <iframe id="example" width="800" height="500"></iframe>




Adding a basic style sheet to the xml is an option <?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>

I tried that, sadly it removes the document tree and instead renders as if it was HTML.

Do you have the XML only in a string or only loaded from the local file system? Or is it loaded over HTTP(S)?

That's what you're asking about though: by adding a stylesheet you --unsurprisingly-- tell the browser to style your nodes, i.e. they stop getting rendered as an XML structure and instead they get rendered as a normal DOM with styling would. The easiest solution here would just be to ignore the warning: it's telling you what the browser's, it's not a warning "about your XML".

That example doesn't work in Chrome.

@MartinHonnen generated in the browser as part of the app. Making an interactive XML tutorial like web application. Trying to render the XML generated so students can see the XML with the interactive show/hide the nodes in the tree. FireFox's rendering of XML is perfect but sadly looks like FF is the only one.

Browsers support XSLT 1.0 and there are XSLT 1.0 solutions like https://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/ to serialize an XML document to its string representation, in the browser you can apply XSLT 1.0 with XsltProcessor. Or integrate SaxonJS 2 (it is available as a client-side JavaScript library from Saxonica) in your app and then you just have to call the XPath 3.1 function serialize on your XML DOM tree.

FYI the warning goes away even if the stylesheet is not found <?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/content/xml/XMLPrettyPrint.css_"?> (added an underscore at the end)

This look promising: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xml-viewer

Browser inconsistencies make a built-in solution almost useless.
Instead you will likely need to use a custom tool that will do this for you. For example this React component will do like you asked.
